# What is the point of this.prmtr = prmtr?

Tags: javascript, parameters, this

In every single game tutorial I encounter this statement of code:

```
function example(parameter) {
/*What does this do?*/ 
this.parameter = parameter;
//and:
this.parameterTwo = function() { /*code*/};
}
```

What is the point of this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Hi! This is a practice common in Object Oriented Programming. It takes an external value and assigns it to an internal state so the passed in value can be reused at a later time or exposed publicly.

Comment: It sets an instance variable to the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty broad question, but basically you are making a function and passing data into it.  You can set those passed in params to variables that are attached (via `this.`) to the instance of the function you create using the 'new' key word.  You then can act upon those attached variables, or in our case with the function `parameterTwo`, you can have it do something, such as return what was passed in and add a '!' to it...

```js
function example(parameter){
    this.parameter = parameter; 
    this.parameterTwo = function(){return this.parameter + "!";}
}
    
var game = new example("hello");
    
console.log(game.parameterTwo());
```

Comment: Just another question... :) why did you use NEW example('hello')?

Comment: you use 'new' to make an independent instance of the function - so you could do : var game = new example("hello");  and var game2 = new example("good bye");  now you can do game.parameterTwo() and game2.parameterTwo() and get the different results.